# Transparency using ArcGIS Server JavaScript API via REST

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, arcgis-rest-api

I am using ArcGIS server 9.3.1 Javascript API via REST.

I have two map services , one is tiled service returns a `satellite image` , and the other is dynamic displays the `roads ,POIs and Parcels`.

I'm trying to make the dynamic one shows the roads only above the satellite image , but i'm always getting white background with the roads and it covers the satellite image.

Here's my code :

```
map = new esri.Map("mapDiv");
var basemap = new esri.layers.ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer("http://URL_TO_SATELLITE/MapServer");
map.addLayer(basemap);

var imageParameters = new esri.layers.ImageParameters();
imageParameters.format = "png24";
imageParameters.height=100;
imageParameters.width=100;  
imageParameters.layerIds=[7]; // Only Roads !
imageParameters.layerOption = esri.layers.ImageParameters.LAYER_OPTION_SHOW;
imageParameters.transparent=true;   

var entrmap = new esri.layers.ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer("http://URL_TO_DYNAMIC/MapServer",
              {"imageParameters":imageParameters}); 

map.addLayer(entrmap);
```

Comment: can you share some json data from ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer("http://URL_TO_DYNAMIC/MapServer") Query(supported operations) in ArcGIS Services for getting some information about data..

Answer (score 4):

If you set transparency only on one layer in your ArcMap file you should save it as MSD () and NOT mxd and in javascript init ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer with

```
imageParameters.format = "png32";
```

Here are some links to similair posts on ESRI forum:

http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/27413-layer-transparency-not-working

http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/10011-dynamic-layer-transparency

Comment: PNG24 delivers the transparency ... no need for PNG32

Comment: PNG24 as it name states consists of 3 colors, each 8 bytes size. I've read somewhere that Photoshop bring this misconception, because when you save image in PS in 'png24' it saves it in 'png32'. But I might be wrong, please check it out.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a setting in the mxd in arcmap I will look and see what I can find, but I think it's in the document properties.

Comment: I don't need to have it as a transparent all the time , just in case of Aerial image , i want to make the background transparent .

Comment: @Mathboy is there a reason not to make it transparent all the time? There is no penalty really.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [SetVisibleLayers](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/help/jsapi/arcgisdynamicmapservicelayer.htm#setVisibleLayers) method on the ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer, to set only one layer as visible.

This Would be the Code:

```
map = new esri.Map("mapDiv");
var basemap = new esri.layers.ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer("http://URL_TO_SATELLITE/MapServer");
map.addLayer(basemap);

var imageParameters = new esri.layers.ImageParameters();
imageParameters.format = "png24";

var entrmap = new esri.layers.ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer("http://URL_TO_DYNAMIC/MapServer",
              {"imageParameters":imageParameters}); 

              var visible = [7]; // Only Roads !
              entrmap.setVisibleLayers(visible); //<---------This is how you set it

map.addLayer(entrmap);
```

Comment: You have multiple ways to on/off the layers , one of them like what i wrote , and also one of them yours ! but still no transparency !

Comment: @Mathboy: esri.layers.ImageParameters is used in the way that you have only when calling ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer.exportMapImage, Geoprocessor.getResultImage, and Geoprocessor.getResultImageLayer.

If you still do not get a transparent image, something is wrong with your ArcGIS server. Have you tried exporting an image manually from the REST end point? Have you tired consuming the Map service in ArcMap, and switching the layers off and on?

Comment: Yes i tried to open the layers via ArcMap , and everything went perfect , so i'm sure there's something should be in the code to activate the transparency